# Bad changelog from generateChangeLog with MariaDB

Tags: liquibase

I am attempting to generate a change log against a MariaDB server.  I am able to successfully generate a change log, however if I do a dropAll and update to validate that it is useful, there are multiple problems with it.  I have tried using both the native mariadb and MySQL jdbc connectors and both experience these problems.  I am also using liquibase 3.1.1.

The first is that there are deferrable and initiallyDeferred flags which are not supported by MySQL.  The update command specifically calls these out as being invalid flags against MySQL.

Once I remove all of those references in the .xml, attempting to update runs into a sql syntax error because a double datatype is defined as DOUBLE(22) (in the xml).  This is not a valid syntax for a double in mariadb or MySQL.  They accept no parameters, or DOUBLE(m,d); my database is defined as default (no parameters).

Now its trying to create a table with an auto_increment but not specifying that the column is also a key in the create table statement; ie. it's missing the primaryKey constraint.

And I'm sure there are more problems in line as I work my way through the changelog (this is just changeset 116 out of 1500+).

Its almost as if liquibase is creating the changelog based on it thinking the db is a different type (postgres/oracle?).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the problem is that Liquibase is thinking it is an unknown database and doesn't know it is almost mysql. There is an issue open to add mariaDB support (https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1411) but it hasn't been implemented quite yet.

The easiest work-around would be to add an extension:

Create a new liquibase.database.ext.MariaDBDatabase class in your codebase that extends liquibase.database.core.MySQLDatabase and override the isCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseConnection conn) method  that returns true if conn.getDatabaseProductName() equals whatever the MariaDB jdbc driver is returning.

You may also want to override the getDefaultDatabaseProductName() to return "mariadb" instead of MySQL so you can differentiate it with contexts

Comment: I did recently talk to the MariaDB developers and they confirmed that the information_schema Liquibase reads is the same in MariaDB so I would expect it to work fine as long as Liquibase recognizes the correct Database implementation to use